# How to configure my ajax/views function to return a dictionary

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

So I have the following html with an ajax request:

```
  <script>
  $("#search_button").on("click", function(){
            var start_date = $("input[name=\"startdate\"]").val();
            var end_date = $("input[name=\"enddate\"]").val();
            var machine_id = $("#machine_id").val();
//            console.log(start_date);
//            console.log(end_date);
//            console.log(machine_id);
            $.ajax({
                url: ('/reports/machine_search'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'start_date': start_date, 'end_date': end_date, 'machine_id': machine_id},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        })
</script>
```

This is my url.py file with the respective url '/reports/machine_search':

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^login', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'reports', views.reports, name='reports'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^reports/machine_search', csrf_exempt(views.machine_search), name='machine_search'),
    url(r'^test', views.my_view)
]
```

and then the respective views file:

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def machine_search(request):
    test = request.data['start_date']
    print(test)
    run_response = {'test1': 'placeholder1',
                   'test2': 'placeholder2'}
    return JsonResponse(run_response)
```

My problem is, that for the time being I simply want the ajax request to return the dictionary that is created in my views function. However, in my success line in ajax, where I console.log the response, in my console I am receiving the entire html of current page where I am making my ajax request. What or where am I going wrong? I simply want my request to return a dictionary from the views function and be able to access that in my html. Thanks in advance and let me know if I can clarify on anything.

Comment: I think there is an error in `test = request.data['start_date']`. What happens if you hit this `machine_search` api in your browser?

Comment: I think the issue is in your `$.ajax` request here `url: ('/reports/machine_search')` try removing parenthesis, should be `url: '/reports/machine_search'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what happens is the `reports/machine_search` url your ajax calls is triggering the `reports` url in your urls.py, which is presumably the page you are on and so you're getting all of that HTML.

One solution is to add a `$` at the end of reports, so that it will only match `reports` and not `reports/machine_search`

```
url(r'reports$', views.reports, name='reports'),
```

Another is to place `reports/machine_search` above `reports`.

Comment: This was the problem! Adding a '$' to the end of the reports url fixed it. I was unaware of that functionality. Thanks so much. @user6731765